# How do I preserve type information across an <xsl:if> statement?

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, saxon

I'm using Saxon 9.4 and XSLT 2.0

I have the following code snippet in my stylesheet :-

```
<xsl:template name="some_template">
  <xsl:param name="some_param" as="xs:integer?"/>
</xsl:template>
```

This is basically a template that takes in an optional integer parameter. When I try to call it like this however,

```
<xsl:call-template name="some_template>
  <xsl:with-param name="some_param">
    <xsl:if test="some_condition">
      <xsl:value-of select="xs:integer(./@attr div 20)"/>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:with-param>
</xsl:call-template>
```

I get an error message saying :-

> ```
> Validation error 
>   FORG0001: Cannot convert zero-length string to an integer
> ```

However, the following two stylesheets don't give me an error :-

```
<xsl:call-template name="some_template>
  <xsl:with-param name="some_param">
    <xsl:value-of select="xs:integer(./@attr div 20)"/>
  </xsl:with-param>
</xsl:call-template>
```

or

```
<xsl:variable name="dummy" as="xs:integer?">
  <xsl:if test="some_condition">
    <xsl:value-of select="xs:integer(./@attr div 20)"/>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:call-template name="some_template>
  <xsl:with-param name="some_param" select="$dummy"/>
</xsl:call-template>
```

So clearly the type information is not being preserved across the  block. Any idea how to get the first thing to work? The third stylesheet does what I want semantically but I'd rather not go around creating (several) dummy variables just to be able to do this.

Thanks!

Comment: `value-of` always produces a text node, try `xsl:sequence` instead.

Comment: Please, provide a complete (but short) transformation, so that we could repro the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:call-template name="some_template">
      <xsl:with-param name="some_param" select=
       "if(some_condition)
          then xs:integer(@attr div 20)
          else ()
      "/>
    </xsl:call-template>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template name="some_template">
  <xsl:param name="some_param" as="xs:integer?"/>
  XXX
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on each of the following XML documents:**

```
<t attr="20">
 <some_condition/>
</t>
```

,

```
<t>
 <some_condition/>
</t>
```

,

```
<t attr="20">
</t>
```

and

```
<t>
</t>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result (without raising any exceptions):**

```
  XXX
```

Comment: this works and Michael Kay's answer sort of explains why (although I'm not sure I understood it completely).

Comment: @owagh, Any use as a number of something that isn't castable to a number, is type-incompatible. This results in an error in XPath 2.0. In XPath 1.0 there is no error and the thing is converted to `NaN`.

Comment: Right but I was expecting that in the false case it would convert it to an empty sequence but apparently it converts it to a document node with no children instead which is not type-castable to an xs:integer.

Comment: @owagh, The way it is in your code -- yes a temporary tree is created. This is a bad habit. Always when possible use the `select` attribute to really get a value and not a tree.

Answer (score 1):

I reckon the error come when your `<xsl:if>` is false meaning no value is assigned to your param. You can try one of this solution :

#### Default value

Did you tried to set a default value for your `<xsl:param>` ?

```
<xsl:template name="some_template">
  <xsl:param name="some_param" select="-1" as="xs:integer?" />
</xsl:template>
```

#### Managing `false` case

Always set a value when you call your template using [XPath2.0 if-then-else expression](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#id-conditionals):

```
<xsl:call-template name="some_template>
  <xsl:with-param name="some_param" select="
     if (some_condition) 
     then xs:integer(./@attr div 20)
     else -1"
  />
</xsl:call-template>
```

I use `-1` as value for the `false` case.

Comment: Did you try my syntax cause you use  `<xsl:value>` "element inserts a text string [...] specified by the select attribute" in your `<xsl:param>` (see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256181.aspx)

Comment: Yes you were right. It does fail when the condition is false.

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear to me what's happening here, but what is clear is how to improve your code so it's not so confusing. With your code as written, in the true case you are computing a double, converting that to an integer, converting the integer to a text node, wrapping that in a document node, passing the document node as the parameter, having this atomized to untyped atomic at the receiving end because the expected type is atomic, then having the untyped atomic value converted to an integer. All this should work, but is really circuitous, and is easily avoided by an "as="xs:integer"" on the xsl:with-param.

In the false case, you are passing a document node with no children, and conversion of that to xs:integer? will fail - it won't convert to an empty sequence. So despite what you say, I think it's failing on the false path.